# HackersEarth - Reverse primes

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge, primes, palindrome

> Generate as many distinct primes P such that reverse (P) is also prime
>   and is not equal to P.
>
> Output: Print per line one integer( ≤ 10^15 ). Don't print more than
>   10^6 integers in all.
>
> Scoring: Let N = correct outputs. M = incorrect outputs. Your score
>   will be max(0,N-M).
>
> Note: Only one of P and reverse(P) will be counted as correct. If both
>   are in the file, one will be counted as incorrect.
>
> Sample Output: 107 13 31 17 2
>
> Explanation
>
> Score will be 1. Since 13,107,17 are correct. 31 is incorrect because
>   13 is already there. 2 is incorrect.
>
> Time Limit: 2 sec(s) for each input file. Memory Limit: 256 MB Source
>   Limit: 25 KB

```
public class ReversePrime {

    final static int MAX = 1000000;
    final static int MAXLISTSIZE = 1000000;
    final static int BASE = 10;

    final static boolean[] isPrime = generatePrime();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Set<Long> reversedCheckedPrime = new LinkedHashSet<Long>();
        int isPrimeLength = isPrime.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < isPrimeLength; i++) {
            if (isPrime[i]) {
                long prime = 2 * i + 3;
                long reverse = reversePrime(prime);
                if ((!(prime == reverse))
                        && (!reversedCheckedPrime.contains(reverse))
                        && (reversedCheckedPrime.size() <= MAXLISTSIZE)) {
                    reversedCheckedPrime.add(prime);
                }
                if (reversedCheckedPrime.size() == MAXLISTSIZE) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (Long prime : reversedCheckedPrime) {
            System.out.println(prime);
        }

    }

    private static long reversePrime(long prime) {
        long result = 0;
        long rem;
        while (prime != 0) {
            rem = prime % BASE;
            prime = prime / BASE;
            result = result * BASE + rem;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean[] generatePrime() {
        int root = (int) Math.sqrt(MAX) + 1;
        root = root / 2 - 1;
        int limit = (int) ((MAX - 1) / 2);
        boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[limit];
        Arrays.fill(isPrime, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < root; i++) {
            if (isPrime[i]) {
                for (int j = 2 * i * (i + 3) + 3, p = 2 * i + 3; j < limit; j = j
                        + p) {
                    isPrime[j] = false;
                }
            }

        }
        return isPrime;
    }
}
```

While the code is working the real concern is the time limit. I'm not able to get it below 2 seconds. How could I further improve the runtime?

One way I reduced it further by avoiding the `println()` call in the `for` loop by doing this:

```
StringBuilder outputResult = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < isPrimeLength; i++) {
            if (isPrime[i]) {
                long prime = 2 * i + 3;
                long revrse = reversePrime(prime);
                if ((!(prime == revrse))
                        && (!reversedCheckedPrime.contains(revrse))
                        && (reversedCheckedPrime.size() <= MAXLISTSIZE)) {
                    reversedCheckedPrime.add(prime);
                    outputResult.append(prime);
                    outputResult.append("\n");
                }
                if (reversedCheckedPrime.size() == MAXLISTSIZE) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(outputResult);
    }
```

[Question link for submission](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/approximate/reverse-primes/)

Comment: You should also link to your previous questions concerning this (IIRC there was something here or on SO).

Comment: @maaartinus This space issue was on SO which you solved .. :)

link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573423/hackerearth-probelm-reverse-primes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Buggy

The output of your code contains many incorrect values.
Looking at the first 10 numbers:

> ```
> 13
> 17
> 19
> 23
> 29
> 37
> 41
> 43
> 47
> 53
> ```

The reverse of 23, 29, 41, 43, 47, 53 are not primes.

#### Making it faster

With a small observation, you can make `reversePrime` much faster:
if the first digit is 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, the reverse cannot be a prime,
and you can stop computing the reverse immediately.

Another thing you can do,
in addition to what @maaartinus suggested,
is to not go all the way until \$10^6\$ primes.
The problem description doesn't say you have to find all the primes,
it just says to not print more than that.

#### Other bad practices

This expression is unnecessarily complicated:

> ```
> if ((!(prime == reverse))
>         && (!reversedCheckedPrime.contains(reverse))
>         && (reversedCheckedPrime.size() <= MAXLISTSIZE)) {
> ```

Instead of `!(prime == reverse)`, it's more intuitive to write `prime != reverse`.

There are so many unnecessary parentheses here that they are just noise and hurt readability.

The way @maaartinus rewrote it is the best of course.

---

The name of the `reversePrime` function,
and the fact that it takes a parameter named `prime` suggests that it works specifically with primes,
but actually it would work with any integer.
It would be better to rename it accordingly to avoid confusion.

Another thing,
it's not a good practice to modify parameter variables.
It's better to copy them to a local variable and use that.
So I would rewrite the function this way:

```
private static long reverse(long num) {
    long result = 0;
    long work = num;
    while (work != 0) {
        long remainder = work % BASE;
        work /= BASE;
        result = result * BASE + remainder;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: About your observation that was pretty nice thing to point .. ! but many incorrect value like ??

Comment: @AnkurAnand All of them? :D I can't see `isPrime[revrse]` anywhere (and fix the typo).

Comment: @maaartinus All of them ? .. by isPrime[revrse] you are suggesting i should check if the the reversed number is also prime or not ? right .. yeah will fix that `revrse` :)

Comment: @maaartinus got what you were saying with  `isPrime[revrse]` .. thank you both of you to point out that .. then actually i've not even understood the questions properly on first go :(

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple idea: From each pair, you generate both the smaller and the bigger prime. You're using a `Set` in order to assure that you don't output both. But this can be done much simpler:

Instead of

```
            long revrse = reversePrime(prime);
            if ((!(prime == revrse))
                    && (!reversedCheckedPrime.contains(revrse))
                    && (reversedCheckedPrime.size() <= MAXLISTSIZE)) {
                reversedCheckedPrime.add(prime);
            }
```

use

```
            long revrse = reversePrime(prime);
            if (prime < revrse) {
                reversedCheckedPrime.add(prime);
            }
```

You simply add the smaller one only (which also handles the case of -self-reversed numbers). The test

```
 reversedCheckedPrime.size() <= MAXLISTSIZE
```

was both wrong (should be `<`) and useless (as there's a `break` later).

Now you can replace the `Set` by a `List` and gain some speed. You can gain even more, if you use a `long[]` of length `MAXLISTSIZE` (which should be called `MAX_LIST_SIZE`) as you avoid autoboxing.

Comment: like always that was pretty clean answer and observation .. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

### Quick suggestions

1. As others have pointed out, the algorithm is incorrect because it doesn't check if the reverse is prime or not.
2. Instead of using a linked hash map, you can simply check `if (prime < reverse)` to make sure you don't get any duplicates.

Here is the `main` function after fixing it up:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    StringBuilder outputResult = new StringBuilder();
    int isPrimeLength = isPrime.length;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < isPrimeLength; i++) {
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            int prime    = 2 * i + 3;
            int reverse  = reversePrime(prime);
            if ((reverse & 1) == 0)
                continue;

            if (prime < reverse && isPrime[(reverse-3) >> 1]) {
                outputResult.append(prime);
                outputResult.append("\n");
                if (++count == MAXLISTSIZE) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print(outputResult);
}
```

After making these changes and setting `MAX` to `100000000`, I was able to generate 308618 "reverse primes" in 0.55 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .. yeah i figured out that yesterday after their comment about buggy thing.. 308618  is my score too there yesterday .. Thank you for conforming me that this will the highest score ..:D
my submission https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/1909283/

Comment: @AnkurAnand If you want to look at the ultimate solution, take a look [at this submission](https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/215019/), which used separate sieves on numbers starting with 1,3,7,9 because the other numbers can't possibly work.  This solution was able to get 1000000 results.

Comment: That was just awesome .. even though i'm having hard time understanding things there (no C++ background) i'm trying to figure it out what he has done !